# Subclassed Customized NSView Instatiation

Tags: nsview

Using xcode 10.2.1, swift 5, and story boards, I drag a custom view object from the library onto the NSView.  I then create a file and subclass the NSView.  My question is this:  where does the subclassed NSView get intantiated??  I have always hated apple for hiding all this from programmers...at least that is how I feel.

I am asking this question, because I want this subclassed NSView to talk with a text field.  In short, as the mouse moves around in the subclassed NSView, I want the coordinates to be displayed in the textfield.

If it sounds like I am unclear about things, that is because I am.  I am still new to cocoa.

Comment: The view gets instatantiated when the view is loaded from the storyboard. Did you set the class of the view in the Identity Inspector?

Comment: I did set the class of the custom view in the Identity Inspector?  I guess what I want is to be able to have the object or a reference for that object so that i can grab the mouse coordinates and then put them into the textfield.  Does that make sense?  Is a global variable my best option?

Comment: Is an [outlet](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ConnectingObjectstoCode.html) what you're looking for?